# How to get Service from another class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm creating telegram bot with Spring-Boot. I have AscractState class:

```
public abstract class AbstractState {
    boolean isInputIndeed = Boolean.FALSE;
    public abstract void handleInput(BotContext context);
//another parts
}
```

And there is extend which is

```
@Slf4j
public class AgeInputState extends AbstractState {

    @Autowired
    ClientService clientService;

    public AgeInputState(boolean isInputIndeed) {
        super(isInputIndeed, State.AGE_INPUT);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleInput(BotContext context) {
        context.getClient().setAge(Integer.parseInt(context.getInput()));
        clientService.updateUser(context.getClient());
    }
}
```

But i have touble with ClientService. Which annotations on class i need to add for autowiring this fiels?

Answer (score 0):

Since this class has a constructor which *only* accepts a `boolean`, I assume you're needing to make *lots* of them.

Spring won't know you're wanting to load these as spring beans if you call this constructor directly.  So creating these through a *factory* of some sort would be one way to go.  Something like:

```java
@Configuration
public class AgeInputStateFactory {

    private @Autowired ClientService clientService;

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype") // Makes a new one each time...
    public AgeInputState create(final boolean isInputIndeed) {
        return new AgeInputState(this.clientService, isInputIndeed);
    }
}
```

Along with a *newly* designed `AgeInputState` constructor which *also* takes the `ClientService` field.

```java
public class AgeInputState extends AbstractState {
    private final ClientService clientService;

    // Package private constructor so that no one outside
    // of this package will call it.  This means you can
    // (try your best to) limit the construction to the
    // factory class. 
    AgeInputState(final ClientService clientService,
                  final boolean isInputIndeed) {
        super(isInputIndeed, State.AGE_INPUT);

        this.clientService = clientService;
    }
}
```

And then all you would do is wherever you need to create these `AgeInputState` `Object`s, you would `@Autowire` the `AgeInputStateFactory` instance, and call the `create` method whenever you need one.